# Updating array values using two masks a[mask1][mask2]=value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array and a mask, we can assign new values to the positions that are TRUE in the mask:

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
mask1 = (a==2) | (a==5)
a[mask1] = 100
print a
# [  1 100   3   4 100   6]
```

However, if we apply a second mask over the first one, we can access to the values but we cannot modify them:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
mask1 = (a==2) | (a==5)
mask2 = (a[mask1]==2)
print a[mask1][mask2]
# [2]
a[mask1][mask2] = 100
print a
# [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]
```

Why does it happen?

(Even if it seems a bizarre way to do this. Just out of curiosity)

Comment: Solutions posted here might help you to understand the issue at hand. To resolve it, one way would be : `a[np.where(mask1)[0][mask2]] = 100`.

Comment: Chained indexing only works if the first index produces a view.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you **mix getters** and **setters** preventing **backpropagation**.

It's because you use `mark1` as an indexer:

```
>>> mask1
array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

now by setting `a[mask1] = 100`, you will set all the elements where `mask1` was true thus resulting in

```
>>> a
array([  1, 100,   3,   4, 100,   6])
```

note that you have only called a "setter" so to speak on `a`.

Now for `a[mask1][mask2] = 100` you actually call both a getter and setter. Indeed you can write this as:

```
temp = a[mask1] #getter
temp[mask2] = 2#setter
```

as a result **you only set the value in the `temp`**, and thus the value is not "*backpropagated*" so to speak to `a` itself. You should see `temp` as a *copy* (although internally it is definitely possible that a python interpreter handles it differently).

**Note**: note that there can be circumstances where this behavior works: if `temp` is for instance a *view* on an array, it could support backwards propagation. [This page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) for instance shows ways to return a view instead of a *copy*.

Answer (score 3):

You are chaining [advanced](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)* indexing operations for the assignment, which prevents the value 100 being written back to the original array.

`a[mask1]` returns a new array with a copy of the original data. Writing `a[mask1][mask2] = 100` means that this *new* array is indexed with `mask2` and the value 100 assigned to it. This leaves `a` unchanged.

Simply viewing the items will appear to work fine because the values you pick out from the copy `a[mask1]` are the values you would want from the original array (although this is still inefficient as data is copied multiple times).

**advanced (or "fancy") indexing is triggered with a boolean array or an array of indices. It always returns a new array, unlike [basic indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) which returns a view onto the original data (this is triggered, for example, by slicing).*