# Assign to Logical Indexed Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, I know that you can do this by doing

```
>>> arr[mask] = value
```

However, if I want to make the code shorter (and not recompute the mask and index each time), I'd like to do something like this:

```
>>> sub = arr[mask]
>>> sub[...] = value # This works in other cases, but not this one.
```

My understanding is that doing `Ellipses` indexing should allow you to specify that you're not reassigning a given variable, but are rather broadcasting to the actual array.

So, here's the question: why doesn't it work?

My thinking is that it's related to the fact that:

```
>>> arr[mask] is arr[mask]
False
```

But surely since the mask indexed versions are just views (not copies of the underlying structure), this shouldn't break assignment.

Comment: Maybe...because `sub` is a value, it can be change to everything. So `sub = arr[mask]` will change `sub` to `arr[mask]`(now, sub is a string). But `sub = value` will change `sub` to `value`(sub also is a string), it wouldn't change `arr[mask]` to `value`?

Comment: Seems very close if not a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/32739828/3293881

Comment: @KevinGuan If you read my question properly, I didn't write `sub = arr[mask]`, I wrote `sub[...] = arr[mask]` which forces the modification of `sub`.

Comment: @cyphar Oops, I didn't pay attention on it. Sorry about that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But surely since the mask indexed versions are just views (not copies of the underlying structure), this shouldn't break assignment.

The reason why this doesn't work is that indexing with masks [*will* create a copy, not a view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

> Advanced indexing always returns a *copy* of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a [*view*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view)).

Answer (score 2):

`arr[mask]` is a copy.  `arr[mask]=...` looks the same, but actually is a different assignment operation.  Elsewhere I've explained this in terms of calls to `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.